# How to debug Firefox add-on update

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a migration update from XUL to Jetpack. I want to simulate the process on my local machine, make sure that everything works as expected when the versions change.

I followed all the steps of this tutorial:
http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/automatic-firefox-extension-updates/ in order to make a self hosted update version. But the extension won't update and I'm not getting any errors.

How can I debug, or at least initiate the update process for an add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should toggle on the `extensions.logging.enabled` preference. This will dump a lot of information about the update process and states into the Browser Console.
After enabling the preference, just open the Add-ons Manager UI and search for updates again.

But to test that stuff still works from going from one version to another, I would just install the old version (in a new profile) and then drop the new version XPI. This will trigger the same code paths as would have been triggered if the update XPI was retrieved over the network.

Comment: Just add the new XPI will trigger the update? Also, I don't see a "search for updated" button

Comment: Sure, the Addon Manager will essentially just replace one XPI with another XPI during an update. That well button has a "Check for updates" sub-menu item.